# Elixir Phoenix Absinthe GraphQL API authentication in both web and mobile app's

Tags: graphql, elixir, phoenix-framework, absinthe

I'm working on an Absinthe GraphQL API for my app. I'm still learning the procedure(so please go easy on me).

I've a Absinthe/GraphQL `MyAppWeb.schema.ex` file in which I use for my queries and mutations. My question is how do I use this API for authenticating the user on both Mobile and Web app?

How do set a cookie(httpOnly & secure) in my web app and access/refresh tokens in a single Absinthe API to serve my website and mobile app. Basically what I'm trying to learn is how do I authenticate the user based on specific platform.

If my question sounds bit confusing, I would be happy to provide more information related to my question. I would really be grateful if someone could explain the procedure, I've been very stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using authentication mechanisms provided by absinthe(if there are any). Depending on what front-end you are using, I would go with JSON API authentication. The flow on server goes the following way:

1. Create a endpoint for login that will receive a user and password and will return a refresh token.
2. Create a endpoint for exchanging refresh token for access token.
3. Use a library like [guardian](https://hexdocs.pm/guardian/Guardian.html) to generate your refresh/access tokens.
4. Create a phoenix [plug](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/plug.html) for authentication that will check your tokens, guardian has some built-in plugs for this.

Now on device you have to implement:

1. Ability to save refresh and access token on device.
2. Have a global handler for injecting access token on authorized requests.
3. Have a global handler for case when access token is expired. (you usually check if your request returns Unauthorized, then you should request a new access token from the server using your refresh token)

This seems like a crude implementation, however I would advise in implementing your system instead of using a black box library that you have no idea how it works under the hood.

Comment: thanks man. I really appreciate the help. This works fine for mobile devices(like in my case I'm using react-native, I can store the token in AsyncStorage). Where as when it comes to website, where shall I store the token?(I've read somewhere that localstorage is vulnerable for XSS attacks). So storing the token in httpOnly cookie is one option, but javascript can not access such type of cookie to set a `Authorization` header..

Comment: xss protection should be handled at input level, not at storage level. If you are using a framework, sanitation of input is already implemented so you can safely put it in local storage.